# MySQL workbench Hangs in Opening Models

Tags: 12.04, mysql-workbench

I have upgraded MySQL workbench to one in repos (I purged the first version). It works fine with Server adminstration and it opens fine previously opened file on startup but when I open another file I get the dialog to confirm closure of current file and program hangs...until I force quit.

I have googled and it seems no body else is affected. Before I upgraded to Natty I had updated Gimp to 2.8 that affected some software (shotwell being one of them and now it works fine) .

I've run out of ideas and I welcome any help

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks God for this Idea, I tried and it worked. It seems the current configurations left by previous version are somehow incompatible with previous ones or something corrupted. So I did this command (be careful the directories are right as there is no undo)

```
cd ~/
rm -rfv .mysql/workbench/
```

**Note that this does not fix the problem of program hanging when using using recent files menu. So do not use recent files with this workaround**

Comment: I resolved this problem on Windows 10 by removing `/users/~username~/AppData/Roaming/Mysql` folder. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Great that you solved it!

Comment: You can also backup your existing connections prior deletion: `cp ~/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml /tmp && rm -rf ~/.mysql/workbench/* &&  mv /tmp/connections.xml ~/.mysql/workbench`